# MySql query- return data that is not present in the past 12 months

Tags: mysql

I have a question. how do i write this query? I am very new to mysql and i get very confused sometimes. please help me. 
thanks

"Adult Canadian Members who haven't accumulated at XYZ in the past 12 months"

I would try something like this:
Select individuals from members where country='CA' and acc_score = 'N' and Reg_date> date_sub(current_date()-365);

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateDiff() Function,

Accumulated within 12 Months,

```
 Select individuals from members 
    where country='CA' 
    and acc_score = 'N' 
    and DATEDIFF(Reg_date,currdate()) between 0 and  365;
```

Accumulated before 12 Months,

```
 Select individuals from members 
    where country='CA' 
    and acc_score = 'N' 
    and DATEDIFF(Reg_date,currdate()) >  365;
```

Additional Info about Datediff() **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT individuals // Select the row names separated by comma, or SELECT * to select all rows 

FROM members //the table name

WHERE country='CA' 
AND acc_score = 'N' 
and DATEDIFF(Reg_date,currdate()) > 365;
```

According to this query, you need a parameter such as a date which says when the `user last accumulated` at XYZ, without that the only thing you can use is acc_score.

If **acc_score is 0 or whatever the minimum amount is and the user registered more than 12 months ago**, that means he didn't accumate at XYZ at all